# "How to fix 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Font has already been added' error in Android Q?"

Tags: android

I have to try new features in Android Q (Hyphenation is off by default in Android Q and AppCompat v1.1.0) and I have also read the document. When I follow the instructions which are in the Android blog it works fine, but when I try to follow the document I found the error.

I just use an only single font family. The code below is running:

```
tvTest.typeface = Typeface.CustomFallbackBuilder(
            FontFamily.Builder(
                Font.Builder(resources.assets, "aguafina_script.ttf").build()).build())
        .addCustomFallback(FontFamily.Builder(
                Font.Builder(resources.assets, "Font_Solid_900.otf").build()).build())
        .build()
```

But when I try to add multiple font families that time I got the error.

```
  Font regularFont = new Font.Builder("regular.ttf").build();
  Font boldFont = new Font.Builder("bold.ttf").build();
  FontFamily family = new FontFamily.Builder(regularFont)
      .addFont(boldFont).build();
  Typeface typeface = new Typeface.CustomFallbackBuilder(family)
      .setWeight(Font.FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD)  // Set bold style as the default style.
                                         // If the font family doesn't have bold style font,
                                         // system will select the closest font.
      .build();
```

Above code is given in the document
        https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/Typeface.CustomFallbackBuilder.html

So can you please help me to solve that error?

Comment: Please post the full error log..

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Font {path=null, style=FontStyle { weight=400, slant=0}, ttcIndex=0, axes=, localeList=, buffer=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=656568 cap=656568]} has already been added
        at android.graphics.fonts.FontFamily$Builder.addFont(FontFamily.java:100)

Answer (score 30):

This error shows up in Android 10 with androidx.core (or core-ktx) version 1.2.0 and higher when you try to register multiple fonts with the *same style and weight* into the same font family.

Although your example is creating the font family programmatically, most developers will run into this error when using the font XML, so let's start with that.

In the font XML, we can't have more than one `font` element with the same `fontStyle` and `fontWeight` attributes. For example, the following XML would cause this error, because both `font` elements have the same values for the style and weight:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:font="@font/gibson_regular"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400" />
    <font
        android:font="@font/gibson_bold"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400" />
</font-family>
```

Even though the value of `font` is different (`@font/gibson_regular` vs `@font/gibson_bold`), the `fontStyle` and `fontWeight` are the same, so this causes the error.

Also, note that if you do not provide the `fontStyle` or `fontWeight` attributes, they default to `normal` and `400` respectively, so this next example also fails:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:font="@font/gibson_regular"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400" />
    <font
        android:font="@font/gibson_bold" />
</font-family>
```

To fix the issue, make sure that the *combination* of `fontStyle` and `fontWeight` for each `font` element is unique. For example, if we properly set the `fontWeight` for the `gibson_bold` font, we will avoid the error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:font="@font/gibson_regular"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400" />
    <font
        android:font="@font/gibson_bold"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="700" />
</font-family>
```

Now, when building this out programmatically, as you are above, the same rules apply. It looks like the API docs that you're referencing haven't been updated to match what the source code is actually doing. Here's how your example should look now:

```kotlin
val regularFont: Font = Font.Builder(resources.assets,"regular.ttf").build()
val boldFont: Font = Font.Builder(resources.assets, "bold.ttf").build()
val family: FontFamily = FontFamily.Builder(regularFont).addFont(boldFont).build()

val typeface: Typeface = CustomFallbackBuilder(family)
    .setStyle(FontStyle(FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD, FONT_SLANT_UPRIGHT))
    .build()
```

When writing it programmatically like this, it appears that Android properly notes the weight and style of the fonts when loading them in via the `Font.Builder`, so as long as `regular.ttf` and `bold.ttf` differ in their weight and style, this code will work fine.

But you can still get this exception if the two fonts have the same weight and style, or if you manually specify the font and style to be the same, such as if you were to call `setWeight(400)` on the bold font.

In summary, when using the font XML, always specify the `fontStyle` and `fontWeight` for each font. And regardless of whether you're writing things with XML or building them out programmatically, make sure that the combination of weight and style is unique for each font in a font family.

Comment: Thank You @Dave Leeds. A very well explained answer.

Comment: good answer. i have to use two font to support api 25 and lower. changing weight of font worked for me

Comment: I owe you my sanity sir.

Comment: This probably saved me an hour or three of debugging just now.

Answer (score 10):

**Disclaimer**: My case wasn't the same as yours, but the **error** was the same. I just want to help whoever lands to this question, because it's the only one that the error is mentioned. Maybe it helps the OP, too.

As it turns out, the culprit was my font-family xml file. Even though my file was perfectly functional for Android 9 and below, it was failing for Android 10(Q). The reason was that I was defining more than one fontStyles as "normal":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:font="@font/dosis_regular"/>

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:font="@font/dosis_bold"/>

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:font="@font/dosis_light"/>

</font-family>
```

After I changed it to only one of them being "normal", it worked just fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:font="@font/dosis_regular"/>

    <font
        app:fontWeight="700"
        app:font="@font/dosis_bold"/>

    <font
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:font="@font/dosis_light"/>

</font-family>
```

Comment: It only started happening for us in Android 10 after we added `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0` dependency in one of our modules. Removing this dependency or your solution both resolve the crash for us.

Answer (score 0):

1)click app as the root folder, right click on it and select : New -> Folder -> create assets Folder,
You would get a Dialog : Create a source root for assets

2)include the .ttf files in your assets folder

[image]

3) use in your activity or fragment like this

```
TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
    Typeface pick_text = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(),  "fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf");
    name.setTypeface(pick_text);

    TextView desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_orderid);
    Typeface desc_text = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(),  "fonts/NevisBold-KGwl.ttf");
    desc.setTypeface(desc_text);
```